# How to solve `Argument of type _ is not assignable to parameter of type 'T1'.` when using multiple generics

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

I am attempted to call a function with two generics, but receive an error that the type is not assignable.

```
abstract class foo<T1, T2> {
    protected readonly generic1 : T1;
    protected readonly generic2 : T2
    constructor(t1: T1, t2: T2) {
        this.generic1 = t1;
        this.generic2 = t2;
    }
}

class bar<T1, T2> extends foo<T1, T2>
{
    constructor()
    {
        super(new someObject(), new otherObject());
    }

    public myFunction()
    {
        // I want to retain type information
        this.generic1.someMethod();
        this.generic2.otherMethod();
    }
}

// Objects that have nothing in common, so can't interface them
class someObject { 
    public someMethod() { };
}
class otherObject { 
    public otherMethod() { };
}
```

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20foo%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20readonly%20generic1%20%3A%20T1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20readonly%20generic2%20%3A%20T2%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(t1%3A%20T1%2C%20t2%3A%20T2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.generic1%20%3D%20t1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.generic2%20%3D%20t2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20bar%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%20extends%20foo%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(new%20someObject()%2C%20new%20otherObject())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20myFunction()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20I%20want%20to%20retain%20type%20information%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.generic1.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.generic2.otherMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20someObject%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someMethod()%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20otherObject%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20otherMethod()%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: That's because "" is of type 'string' and T1 and T2 are not necessarily. Does bar implement a string version of foo?

Comment: You've modified the code in an edit, but the problem is unchanded. `T1` could be anything, so `someObject` cannot always be a `T1`.

Comment: Why `bar` is generic? Why not make it just  `class bar extends foo<someObject, otherObject>`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing in a `string` to unspecified type parameters `T1` and `T2`. How can you say that string is a valid value in either of those types?

If you were to say

```
class bar extends foo<string, string>
```

then it would work. But that doesn't seem like what you're trying to accomplish. What are you trying to be able to do?

---

Your extended example:

Nothing has changed here. Why do you want to make `bar` itself generic? It looks like `bar` is going to fulfill `foo`'s generics with concrete classes, which means `bar` doesn't need to be generic at all.

```
class bar extends foo<someObject, otherObject>
```

Comment: I extended my example

Comment: doh, so simple. Thanks!